# nwjs builder won't change my exe icon

Tags: node-webkit, nwjs

I am trying to package my app using nwjs builder and it indeed does get packaged but the problem is with the windows icon. The title bar one works perfectly with a png file with a transparent background, but I spent hours on this and followed instructions but still the windows icon won't change.

This is the "main" command line I'm using: `nwb nwbuild -v 0.21.2 -p win64 Desktop/app -o Desktop/app2 --production --with-ffmpeg --win-ico icon.ico`

When I run this, it does what it does and the app gets packaged and everything but the application icon is the main/default NW.js one. I even tried using resource hacker and replaced the icon, saved and exited but still. The same NW.js icon.

Is this a problem from windows 10 or something? or maybe the ico image I'm using? I tried several ico generators and tried using different icos but still.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out resource hacker works perfectly but I just needed to move the file to somewhere else (cache reasons). But, the nwjs builder win ico option is still a no go and shouldn't be used since it doesn't get anything done and you'll end up wasting your time. Using resource hacker is very very simple and gets the job done.